# KDB type error when calling function using error trap

Tags: kdb

I have a function that connects to a process, extracts some information and returns it.

```
 func1:{[processName]
        h: hopen getConnDetails[processName];
        sampleData:h"select from tableName where sym=`someSym";
        sampelData:update trueTime:.z.t from sampleData;
        hclose h;
        allData,:sampleData
        allData
       }each processName;
```

The above works absolutely fine when run by itself. But when I try to call this function from init using error trap, I get type error when sampleData is being added to allData.

```
func1:{[processName]
        h: hopen getConnDetails[processName];
        sampleData:h"select from tableName where sym=`someSym";
        sampelData:update trueTime:.z.t from sampleData;
        hclose h;
        allData,:sampleData
        allData
       }

init:{[]
     processName:exec distinct processName from someProcess;
     @[func1;;{Show "Error calling function with error: ",x}]each processName
    }
```

Please note that both func1 and init are in the same namespace.
What am I missing here? Appreciate your insight on this.

Thanks

Comment: Is your definition of `func1` correct? If you have the `each processName` at the end, that means you are assigning `func1` with the result and not the function. Then when you try to "call" it later, it will fail because the variable `func1` contains something that cannot be indexed with the type of `processName`.

Comment: I realized I did not update full code that isn't working. I don't have each processName at the end when I am calling the function from init[]. I have updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: Is it just a type error, or does it include you custom error prefix? Potentially it's the first line of `init` failing instead.

Comment: It is a type error. I debugged the code and it is failing at allData,:sampleData

Comment: You have a typo in your code block `sampelData`